# React JS add component to specific clicked li

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Can't figure out the way to create the following function. I currently load data (local json) into a `li`. Upon click I want to add a new component to the clicked `li` element with data.

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    <li> 
        3 
        <div id="data">
        <!-- appended data -->
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Upon clicking another `li` the previous appended element should be removed and added to the newly clicked `li`. (Row toggle)

If anyone could kick me in the right React direction.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Flowers from 'flowers.json';

class Flowers extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isToggleOn: true
    };

    this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }


  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e);
    console.log('li item clicked! ' + e.currentTarget);
    // appends to clicked div
    e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
  }

  render() {
    const List = Flowers.map((flower) =>
      <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} key={flower.id} id={flower.id}>
        {flower.name}
      </li>
    );

    return(
        <ul>{List}</ul>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Flowers />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add to your state the ID of the flower that is active. 
E.g.

```
this.state = { ActiveFlowerID: null }
```

So when no ActiveFlower none is open.
On handle click method make the change on the state, and render your flowers additional data with an if matching the flower id and the state.

Hope this helps.